# What is the difference between UNIQUE, UNIQUE KEY and CONSTRAINT 'name' UNIQUE?

Tags: mysql, database-design, unique, create-table, unique-constraint

I have a basic `users` table I want to create in MySQL.

I do not want duplicate emails or duplicate usernames appearing in the database.

- What is the best way of preventing this upon table creation?
- And what is the difference between the following:

**1.**
    `UNIQUE (username), UNIQUE (email),`

**2.**
    `UNIQUE KEY (username), UNIQUE KEY (email),`

**3.**
    `CONSTRAINT ucons_login UNIQUE (username, email),`

I assume some of these are synonymous, yet I've been reading conflicting information online and was seeking confirmation.

I hope someone can assist.

**The SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  pass CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  registration_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  user_level TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  active CHAR(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  UNIQUE (username),
  UNIQUE (email),
  INDEX login (email, pass),
  INDEX full_name (last_name, first_name)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: ps: the index for email,pass will probably only make things slower. The unique constraint on email can work as a normal index as well. Selects on email will return at most 1 row so there is no need to also index on pass.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1 and 2 are identical - both create two unique indexes, one for each key. #3 only creates one unique index across both keys, so no combination of username and email can be duplicated, but for example, a username could be duplicated as long as a different email was used.

Sounds like you probably want either of the first two. UNIQUE and UNIQUE KEY are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

They are all synonymous as evidenced by [syntax documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY]
      [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option]
```

`[]` in this notation ([Wirth's notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirth_syntax_notation)) denote optional elements

Comment: The third one is a complex key across multiple fields, as opposed to two distinct keys.

Comment: Indeed... I didn't notice that in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the link the MySQL create table syntax is starting to make more sense now.