# UNIQUE CONSTRAINT Meaning in CREATE TABLE SPONSORSHIP

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I would like to know the meaning of the UNIQUE constraint, it is a generated script, it concerns sponsorship, it does not have to be rather?

```
CONSTRAINT PARRAINAGE_PERSONNE_COMPTE_AK UNIQUE (id_pers_cpt, id_pers_cpt_PERSONNE_COMPTE)
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE PARRAINAGE
(
    id_parrainage               Int  Auto_increment  NOT NULL ,
    date                        Date NOT NULL ,
    id_pers_cpt                 Int NOT NULL ,
    id_pers_cpt_PERSONNE_COMPTE Int NOT NULL ,
    id_etab                     Int,
    CONSTRAINT PARRAINAGE_PK PRIMARY KEY (id_parrainage)
   ,CONSTRAINT PARRAINAGE_PERSONNE_COMPTE_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_pers_cpt) REFERENCES PERSONNE_COMPTE(id_pers_cpt)
   ,CONSTRAINT PARRAINAGE_PERSONNE_COMPTE0_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_pers_cpt_PERSONNE_COMPTE) REFERENCES PERSONNE_COMPTE(id_pers_cpt)
   ,CONSTRAINT PARRAINAGE_ETABLISSEMENT1_FK FOREIGN KEY (id_etab) REFERENCES ETABLISSEMENT(id_etab)
   ,CONSTRAINT PARRAINAGE_PERSONNE_COMPTE_AK UNIQUE (id_pers_cpt)

)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: It means that the values of `id_pers_cpt` cannot be duplicated.  They are unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between UNIQUE, UNIQUE KEY and CONSTRAINT 'name' UNIQUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201584/what-is-the-difference-between-unique-unique-key-and-constraint-name-unique)

Comment: It is a generated script, it concerns sponsorship, it does not have to be rather? CONSTRAINT PARRAINAGE_PERSONNE_COMPTE_AK UNIQUE (id_pers_cpt, id_pers_cpt_PERSONNE_COMPTE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table relates two persons it seems:

- id_pers_cpt
- id_pers_cpt_PERSONNE_COMPTE

The constraint

```
CONSTRAINT PARRAINAGE_PERSONNE_COMPTE_AK UNIQUE (id_pers_cpt)
```

assures that a `id_pers_cpt` can only appear once in the table. Thus an `id_pers_cpt_PERSONNE_COMPTE` can be related to many `id_pers_cpt`, but an `id_pers_cpt` can only be related to one `id_pers_cpt_PERSONNE_COMPTE`.

This makes this a `pers_cpt` table, with one record per `id_pers_cpt`. If you want to allow an `id_pers_cpt` to be related to multiple `id_pers_cpt_PERSONNE_COMPTE`, then you need the constraint you mentioned instead:

```
CONSTRAINT PARRAINAGE_PERSONNE_COMPTE_AK UNIQUE (id_pers_cpt, id_pers_cpt_PERSONNE_COMPTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

- The UNIQUE constraint ensures that all values in a column are
  different.

  Both the UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints provide a guarantee for
  uniqueness for a column or set of columns.

  A PRIMARY KEY constraint automatically has a UNIQUE constraint.

  However, you can have many UNIQUE constraints per table, but only one
  PRIMARY KEY constraint per table.

In your table `id_parrainage` primary key and `id_pers_cpt` unique key both will never be duplicated

`id_parrainage` column will not allow null value and also
`id_pers_cpt` will not allow null value

Comment: What about null values?

Comment: @jarlh ansi sql will allow many and mysql also but mssql allow one

Comment: Opps sorry thanks i though it ia only unique key i edited